# Length of Decimal Places Including Trailing Zeros

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'd like to return in one cell the number of decimal places from another cell and I can't seem to figure out a formula to include the trailing zeros so that 1.50 returns 2 instead of 1.

Here's what I have:

```
=IF(LEN(AF443)-LEN(INT(AF443)) = 0, 0, LEN(AF443)-LEN(INT(AF443))-1)
```

Not all the decimal places are the same and some have to keep zeros for consistency (e.g. 9.00).

Comment: You'd have to convert it to text in the formula and then measure the length of that instead of how you're doing it.

Comment: maybe `=INT(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("format",A1),"F",""))`, but it doesn't auto update when the cell format changes.

Comment: Got it.  Is there a way to format the entire column to text but keep the decimals, since it automatically removes them?

Comment: you can use `'` in front of any value to show it as text - `'1.50`, or just change the format to Text

Comment: So you want to use `LEN(TEXT(AF443,"General"))`

Comment: Actually, I inserted a new column, formatted it to text, then pasted values and that worked.  Thank you!

Comment: Nevermind, I'm still trying to auto format all at once to text without having the numbers with trailing zeros switch to integers.

Comment: LEN(TEXT(AF443,"General")) is great, but I need to disregard any numbers to the left of the decimal

Comment: @D.R if the value is text, then just `=LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)`, or your version `=MAX(0,LEN(A1)-LEN(INT(A1))-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your number is in cell `B2` try this formula:

```
=RIGHT(CELL("format",B2),-1+LEN(CELL("format",B2)))
```

[image]

Comment: This works for data that are formatted as numbers.  However, I need to keep my column general, otherwise the data gets skewed (decimals are added to make 2500 into 2500.00).